# Why does my Auth0 id_token not contain any information about the user?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, auth0

I started from this [React sample application from Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/react/01-login) and login through Auth0 works fine but does not give me the expected token.

After login the browser localStorage contains an id_token and a profile object. When I decode the id_token I see that the payload contains something like this:

```
{
  "iss": "https://mycompany.eu.auth0.com/",
  "sub": "auth0|5821bc27f92ca3261c628a26",
  "aud": "2A8cgDBm86kLCtCNtUMcKPL2G3oqjIdE",
  "exp": 1478755859,
  "iat": 1478719859
}
```

The profile contains email and lots of other good stuff from the user profile as registered in Auth0.

I need to parse on the token to my API server and therefore I need the attributes from the profile-object to be part of the token. How can I make the id_token contain all these attributes, so that I can parse it in my API-service and store it the first time the user logs in?

As I see it, I cannot use the profile-object found in the browser localStorage as it needs to be signed by Auth0 in order for my API server to trust the information.

I'm also aware that I can use the id_token to make a request from my API server directly to Auth0 to get this additional information, but I just think it would be simpler and more efficient if the information was carried by the token.

Answer (score 2):

Those are the claims included by default in a `id_token`; it's possible to request other claims to be included by passing a `scope` parameter with the appropriate value.

See [Scopes - Requesting specific claims](https://auth0.com/docs/scopes#requesting-specific-claims), for a reference on what you can pass in the `scope` parameter in order to influence the contents of the `id_token`.

Answer (score 0):

To add onto João Angelo's answer, you can't request the entire "App_Metadata" object in scope. If there are app specific fields e.g. lang or favorite color, these have to be called out specifically.

Example App MetaData
[image]

Example call

```html
https://example.auth0.com/authorize
  ?response_type=token
  &client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID
  &redirect_uri=http://jwt.io&connection=google-oauth2
  &scope=openid+lang+favoriteColor
```

There may be additional caveats to the [scope parameter](https://auth0.com/docs/scopes#requesting-specific-claims), it would be good to ask Auth0 as you run into issues